# Bayesian estimation using Gibbs sampling for financial models

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs, finance

I am trying to do Gibbs sampling, from this [paper](http://www.jds-online.com/file_download/353/JDS-746.pdf).

This is a CIR financial model, I want to do Gibbs on its parameters:
$$y(t+{\Delta}^{+})=y(t)+(\alpha-\beta y(t)){\Delta}^{+}+\sigma \sqrt{y(t)}{\epsilon}_{t}$$

The conditionals are:

Step 1: ${y}_{t,j+1}^{*}|{y}_{t,j}^{*},\theta\ \tilde{\ }\ N({y}_{t,j}^{*}+(\alpha-\beta {y}_{t,j}^{*})\Delta, {\sigma}^{2}\Delta {y}_{t,j}^{*})$

Step 2: $\psi|Y,{Y}^{*},{\sigma}^{2}\ \tilde{}\ N(\mu, {\Lambda}^{-1})$

Step 3: $\sigma|Y,{Y}^{*}, \psi\ \tilde{}\ inverse-gamma(E, F)$
$E=(T-1)(M+1)/2$, and $F=\sum\limits_{t=1}^{T-1}{\sum\limits_{j=0}^{M}{\frac{{{\left( y_{t,j+1}^{*}-\left[ y_{t,j}^{*}+(\alpha -\beta y_{t,j}^{*})\Delta  \right] \right)}^{2}}}{2y_{t,j}^{*}}}}$
Repeat Gibbs between step 2 and 3.

Notations: $\theta=(\psi,{\sigma}^{2})$ and $\psi=(\alpha, \beta)$

I get negative numbers when sampling from inverse-gamma, I use rinvgamma().  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The corresponding continuous model is guaranteed to remain positive, but the discrete model does not have that property: $y_t$ can end up negative, and the process is no longer defined after that point. Could this be the cause of your problem?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I said negative, I didn't get negative numbers.  I actually get this...

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd rinvgamma(1, 5323, 32.724) spits out 0.005986. And this is my σ, which is unbelievably small! I tried different dataset, still same thing. I blame the algorithm.

Comment: This may be $\sigma^2$, rather than $\sigma$.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd I see, maybe I am misreading the paper?  But the author says $\sigma$~$IG(1,E,F)$, I did so.  Am I making a mistake? The $\sigma$ is almost 0.

Comment: If you check the computations just before (I have not read them), they were looking at $p(\sigma^2|Y,Y^*,\psi)$: they may have forgotten a square when stating the conclusion.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd Yes, I think I'm with you on the paper might made a mistake, when writing "which hints us to write $\psi|Y, {Y}^{*}, \sigma$ ~$N(\mu, {\Lambda}^{-1})$ "  page 274.

Comment: They missed the square on $\sigma$, I am high suspecting there are other errors too.  Does the author not proof read?  If not, the journal should read it for themselves, no?